# mysql update from array. what do i miss?

Tags: php, mysql

i use a mysql wrapper class to gather datas from form. i need to update a mysql text field called "accommodation" with a string from a loop like that:

```
foreach($_POST['postcode'] as $index => $cp)

    {
        $cp = $cp; 
        $name = $_POST['name'][$index];

        $insert = "$cp,$name;";

    }

$data['accommodation'] = $insert;       

$db->update("circuits_".$_POST['year']."", $data, "type='".$tour."'");
```

if i echo $insert inside the loop everything is fine, i have my complete string. but i need to update the database outside the loop to have the all string. and yet i gather only the last value of the array, not the all string. thanks for your help.

Comment: $name[] = $_POST.. will make it an array.

Comment: just be careful with the possible injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always overwriting the $insert;

Try doing this:

```
$insert .= "$cp,$name;";
```

this way you'll add to the variable, not replace it.

Remember to add $insert = "" before the loop.

Comment: ok so i put `$insert ="";` outside the loop. i add the dot inside the loop and then: $data['accommodation'] = $insert; outside the loop. still no luck. again the last value entered.